# How does this regular expression work exactly?

Tags: python, regex

So I'm learning python and I simply can't get my head around how regular expression works in this [Look-and-Say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence).

I have tried to read the documentation and I understand how methods works and all, but I don't know how the for loop fits in there.

```py
import re

lookAndSay = "1"

lookAndSay = "".join([str(len(j) + 1) + i for i, j in re.findall(r"(\d)(\1*)", lookAndSay)])
print(LookAndSay)
```

the output is

> 11

Comment: Try https://regex101.com, type in the regex and it will break down exactly what it is doing and let you test some input

Comment: You write *I don't know how the for loop* but the question doesn't make clear what you mean by ***the** for loop*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the line of interest into a loop, you hopefully get a better impression of what happens:

```
import re

lookAndSay = "1"

for i in range(5):
    print (lookAndSay)
    lookAndSay = "".join([str(len(j) + 1) + i for i, j in re.findall(r"(\d)(\1*)", lookAndSay)])
```

The regex `(\d)(\1*)` matches (and captures) in the given string all pairs of

1. a digit `(\d)`
2. trailing repetitions of the same digit `(\1*)` if any (the empty string else)

As [huma474](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57580048/2932052) already stated, `(\1*)` in the regex is a capturing back-reference. The `\1` means "what you captured in the **first** pair of parentheses"; the **second** pair of parentheses would be addressed by `\2` and so on ...

BTW: I found the enclosing python stuff much more confusing than the regex itself.

#### Addendum: re.findall explanained

As to understand the part around the regex, it helps to add this two lines of code to the above script:

```
print (lookAndSay)
print (re.findall(r"(\d)(\1*)", lookAndSay))
```

and have a look on its output:

```
1
11
21
1211
111221
312211
[('3', ''), ('1', ''), ('2', '2'), ('1', '1')]
```

The last two lines are

- the final iteration stage and
- the description of it in terms of the regex being used:

  - `(\d)` matches `3`, `(\1*)` matches `` (no more `3`s)
  - `(\d)` matches `1`, `(\1*)` matches `` (no more `1`s)
  - `(\d)` matches `2`, `(\1*)` matches `2` (one more `2`)
  - `(\d)` matches `1`, `(\1*)` matches `1` (one more `1`)

As documented, [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of tuples if there is more then one capturing group in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

The regex function part of that, `re.findall(r"(\d)(\1*)", lookAndSay)`, breaks down to this:

Find all occurrences in the string `lookAndSay` where a single digit (0 - 9) occurs and then find a second set of matches which match the first set. `\1` is how you identify a previous pattern. In this case `\1*` = `(\d)*`, which means match any number of digits that it sees.

The effect of this is this:

```
>>> temp = "1"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"(\d)(\1*)",temp)
[('1', '')]
>>> temp = "11"
>>> re.findall(r"(\d)(\1*)",temp)
[('1', '1')]
>>> temp = "111111"
>>> re.findall(r"(\d)(\1*)",temp)
[('1', '11111')]
```

The rest of that function on that line is a join that joins the 2 sets of matches that are found together without a space.

Without the second pattern, the `\1`, the results of the `findall` would look like this:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\d)",temp)
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Comment: And how would this expression help to find the next value in the sequence from a number like "1211"? That should be "111221"

Comment: The pattern is matching against the concept of a digit, rather that the number 1 specifically, so your match would be ['1','11221'] - or the first digit, (\d),  and then a set of any number of numbers, (\1*) = (\d)*. For POSIX regex on linux that \1 would be the same as [0-9]* when trying to do the match.

Comment: @AndresC12_09 just do the line `lookAndSay = "".join([str(len(j)...` in a loop and see.

Comment: @huma474 maybe it would be better to re-use the result of one step for the next step instead of using `temp`

Comment: The goal of reusing temp was to show the effect of patterns while only the underlying data gets changed between each line.

Comment: @huma474 I found the word *set* confusing here, `\1` is a back-reference to a *captured* match.